# Accessing nested json element safely

Tags: javascript, json

Simple javascript / json question.

In my code I am finding a value for a variable from one of a number of sources (I try each in turn until I find one that is not `undefined`).  One of those sources is a json object with several levels of elements, not all of which are guaranteed to be populated.

Say, for example, the data that I need is found at `options.levelA.levelB.levelC.dataThatINeed`.  None of those levels is guaranteed to be set, including even the options variable itself.

To avoid runtime errors (trying to access a subelement of 'undefined'), is the only safe way to access `dataThatINeed` to do so as follows:

```
var data = (options && options.levelA && options.levelA.levelB && options.levelA.levelB.levelC && options.levelA.levelB.levelC.dataThatINeed) || 'default';
```

It just seems like a very inelegant way to do it, with the real possibility of bugs (typos etc) slipping in with all of those levels to include.  I wonder if there is a better practice to adopt.  It's a shame you can't access `options.levelA.levelB.levelC.dataThatINeed` directly, returning `undefined` if `dataThatINeed` (or any of the higher levels) is `undefined`, rather than possibly throwing an error.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that does indeed address the same issue.  I do wonder why javascript has not been implemented such that an attempt to access a deeply nested element that has undefined elements along the way does not simply result in `undefined` being returned, rather than throwing an error?  To me, `a.b.c` is just as undefined as `a` where `a` has not been defined.

Comment: Just seems really inelegant to have to define kludgy ways of accessing `a.b.c` safely, when returning `undefined` where any of `a`, `b` and `c` is undefined seems to be the logical thing to do anyway.